# How to inject a service in a model class with existing constructors

Tags: javascript, angular, inject

I have an model class with a default constructor and a constructor with parameters.  I also have a service with some methods I would like to use in the model class.  I have the include for the service, but when I attempt to inject the service with the constructor for the service, I get

> "Multiple constructor implementations are not allowed."

Here is an example of what I have attempted:

```
import { MyService } from '../utilities/utils.service';
export class MyData {
private __var1: string;
get var1(): string { return this.__var1; }
set var1(val: string) { this.__var1 = val; }

private __var2: string;
get var2(): string { return this.__var2; }
set var2(val: string) { this.__var2 = val; }

// etc.

constructor()

constructor(
    var1: string,
    var2?: string
) {
    this.__var1 = var1;
    this.__var2 = var2;
}

constructor(private myService: MyService) { };  // causes error.

}
```

I thought this was the correct approach, obviously not.

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998629/typescript-constructor-overload-with-empty-constructor

Comment: jbrown, thank you for the pointer.  I think at this point I am going to try a Helper Class with just the methods and then new that class where I need it rather than attempt to use injection.